# Ant design form updates a field when another field was changed

Tags: reactjs, antd

Let say that I have 2 fields in a form: age, gender. Whenever the age field change, I update the gender field. If age > 18 then gender is boy else gender is girl. Everything works just fine but the console show this error

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

Could you guys show me how to fix this? This is the codesandbox, it is a really small app just to demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-bush-dnqvn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Use defaultValue,   <InputNumber defaultValue={form.age} />

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. It does not work that way since the defaultValue is just for initialization